# Create Null Column in Snowflake Query and Define Data Type

Tags: sql, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a View1 with 15 columns and I would like to Union it to View2 which has 100 columns. The 15 columns in View1 align with 15 of the 100 columns in View2 but from my understanding, I can't Union 2 tables or views in Snowflake unless they have the same set of columns.

Instead, I'm trying to add the other 85 columns with a NULL value to View1 and define it in the View1 query but the data types for those 85 missing columns vary (boolean, string, integer, date, etc). I can write something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW "VIEW1" AS
SELECT FIELD1
      ,FIELD2
      ,...
      ,FIELD15
      ,NULL AS FIELD16
      ,NULL AS FIELD17
      ,...
      ,NULL AS FIELD100
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

But Snowflake is automatically assigning Fields 16-100 a VARCHAR data type which will still create a problem when I go to union View1 and View2. Is there a way to define the data type in the query? Sort of like "NULL AS FIELD16 *BOOLEAN*"? If not, is there another way (or better way) of doing this? I can't alter the source table, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to define the data type in the query? Sort of like "NULL AS FIELD16 BOOLEAN"?*

NULL by design has TEXT data type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 
AS
SELECT NULL AS c;

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE 'v1';
-- DATA TYPE
-- TEXT
```

When set operator [UNION ALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html) is applied the matching column will be subject to [Implicit Casting (“Coercion”)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-type-conversion.html#implicit-casting-coercion).

> General Usage Notes
>
> **Make sure that the data type of each column is consistent across the rows from different sources.**

In order to avoid it, NULL value should be **explicitly** casted to proper data type:

```
CREATE VIEW "VIEW1" AS
SELECT FIELD1
      ,FIELD2
      ,...
      ,FIELD15
      ,NULL::BOOLEAN AS FIELD16
      ,NULL::BOOLEAN AS FIELD17
      ,...
      ,NULL::INT AS FIELD100
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to cast the `NULL` literals to the type you want, e.g.

```sql
CREATE VIEW "VIEW1" AS
SELECT FIELD1,
       FIELD2,
       ...
       FIELD15,
       CAST(NULL AS BOOLEAN) AS FIELD16,
       ...
FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Type casting will clear the data type problem.
[image]